# can we share specific content type in drupal7 multisite?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

```
I have three websites.
1. website1.com
2. website2.com
3 website3.com
```

All are separate websites. Now I am using drupal7 multisite concept [Different database but same code files].
I have shared users, session, auth tables.
Now I want to share content of specific content type "Case_study".

Please let me know.

Comment: you should ask question here http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DushyantJoshi In its current state, no - we'd close it as too broad.

Comment: @Clive not even in drupal.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: No, the current question doesn't meet our standards. It's far too broad; not a specific question but more of a "tutor me through this feature I want to build for my website". That's not the sort of thing we cover on Drupal Answers

Comment: Instead of multi-site you can use Domain access module to achieve this.
https://drupal.org/project/domain

Answer (score 0):

I'd not suggest the sharing approach since node IDs will be site dependent, so you might end up in a situation where sharing that many tables will create conflicts between sites.

Can you provide the data via RSS/REST Api and aggregate from other sites? Also you could build a custom module that handles this, internally switching active database to load a specific node, anyway.. I'd go for RSS/REST first.